# Ruby CSV: How can I read a tab-delimited file?

Tags: ruby, csv

```
CSV.open(name, "r").each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

And I get the following error:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n
```

The name of the file is a .txt tab-delimited file. I made it specifically. I have a .csv file, I went to excel, and saved the file as .txt tab delimited. So it is tab delimited.

Shouldn't `CSV.open` be able to read tab-delimited files?

Comment: What kind of error you have?

Comment: CSV::MalformedCSVError Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "And I get the error." tells us nothing; Specifically *what* error do you get? The name of the file can't be a .txt tab-delimited file, but the file's contents can be text and the fields can be tab-delimited. CSV opens tab-delimited ("TSV") and comma-delimited files ("CSV") but you have to tell the class which one you're dealing with. When asking for help debugging, you need to include a minimal example of the sample input, code that demonstrates the problem and a clear definition of the problem. As is we don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 17):

Try specifying the field delimiter like this:

```
CSV.open("name", "r", { :col_sep => "\t" }).each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

And remember to `require 'csv'` and read the [DOCS](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Comment: I made a small amendment that might help, try that.

Comment: File.open works, but then how do I read the stuff from the file? I then put CSV.read in there, but that throws me back to the same error.

Answer (score 4):

By default `CSV` uses the comma as separator, this comes from the fact that CSV stands for 'Comma Separated Values'.

If you want a different separator (in this case tabs) you need to make it explicit.

**Example**:

```
p CSV.new("aaa\tbbb\tccc\nddd\teee", col_sep: "\t").read
```

Relevant documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#new

Comment: I tried 

somefile = CSV.open(name, col_sep: "\t").read
   puts hello

but it doesn't work, it still throws the same error.

Comment: I think your file might be malformatted then. Can you try this and report results? `p File.read(name)`

Comment: When I do puts, it shows me something like <File:0000193841348> some random number after the :

Comment: Could you please upload your file somewhere so we can test it? I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the file itself at this point.

Comment: @JesusCastello I would have to agree especially since he is getting a `CSV::MalformedCSVError`. Which clearly states the issue is a malformed file.

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to `CSV`, you can also use `smarter_csv` like this:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

data = SmarterCSV.process(filename, col_sep: "\t")
```

If you use `smarter_csv >= 1.4.2`, you can also do this:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

data = SmarterCSV.process(filename, col_sep: :auto)
```

SmarterCSV will return an array of hashes, and can do batch processing